# JVM how to increase constant pool limit

Tags: java, android

After trying to deploy my app, the build failed and the following error was returned.

> File size exceeds configured limit (2560000), code insight features not available

[image: File size exceeds configured limit (2560000), code insight features not available]

I deleted several unecessary libraries and components but the error still exists. All the remaining stuff in my project needs to be there. I know the limit of the Java constant pool is 65535, but is there any way possible to increase this limit?

**R.java file (unnecessary constants that won't go away)**

```
public static final class style {
    public static final int AlertDialog_AppCompat=0x7f0900a2;
    public static final int AlertDialog_AppCompat_Light=0x7f0900a3;
    public static final int Animation_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f0900a4;
    public static final int Animation_AppCompat_DropDownUp=0x7f0900a5;
    public static final int AppPreferenceFragmentCompatStyle=0x7f0900a6;
    public static final int AppPreferenceTheme=0x7f0900a7;
    public static final int AppTheme=0x7f0900a8;
    public static final int Base_AlertDialog_AppCompat=0x7f0900a9;
    public static final int Base_AlertDialog_AppCompat_Light=0x7f0900aa;
    public static final int Base_Animation_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f0900ab;
    public static final int Base_Animation_AppCompat_DropDownUp=0x7f0900ac;
    public static final int Base_DialogWindowTitle_AppCompat=0x7f0900ad;
    public static final int Base_DialogWindowTitleBackground_AppCompat=0x7f0900ae;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat=0x7f090042;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Body1=0x7f090043;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Body2=0x7f090044;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Button=0x7f090027;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Caption=0x7f090045;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Display1=0x7f090046;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Display2=0x7f090047;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Display3=0x7f090048;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Display4=0x7f090049;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Headline=0x7f09004a;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Inverse=0x7f09000b;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Large=0x7f09004b;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Large_Inverse=0x7f09000c;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Light_Widget_PopupMenu_Large=0x7f09004c;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Light_Widget_PopupMenu_Small=0x7f09004d;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Medium=0x7f09004e;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Medium_Inverse=0x7f09000d;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Menu=0x7f09004f;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_SearchResult=0x7f0900af;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_SearchResult_Subtitle=0x7f090050;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_SearchResult_Title=0x7f090051;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Small=0x7f090052;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Small_Inverse=0x7f09000e;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Subhead=0x7f090053;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Subhead_Inverse=0x7f09000f;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Title=0x7f090054;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Title_Inverse=0x7f090010;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Menu=0x7f090097;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Subtitle=0x7f090055;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Subtitle_Inverse=0x7f090056;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Title=0x7f090057;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Title_Inverse=0x7f090058;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionMode_Subtitle=0x7f090059;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionMode_Title=0x7f09005a;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Button=0x7f09005b;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Button_Borderless_Colored=0x7f09009e;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Button_Colored=0x7f09009f;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Button_Inverse=0x7f090098;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_DropDownItem=0x7f0900b0;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_PopupMenu_Header=0x7f09005c;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_PopupMenu_Large=0x7f09005d;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_PopupMenu_Small=0x7f09005e;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Switch=0x7f09005f;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_TextView_SpinnerItem=0x7f090060;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_Widget_AppCompat_ExpandedMenu_Item=0x7f0900b1;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_Widget_AppCompat_Toolbar_Subtitle=0x7f090061;
    public static final int Base_TextAppearance_Widget_AppCompat_Toolbar_Title=0x7f090062;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat=0x7f090063;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_CompactMenu=0x7f0900b2;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f090011;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert=0x7f090012;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_FixedSize=0x7f0900b3;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_MinWidth=0x7f090013;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_DialogWhenLarge=0x7f090001;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light=0x7f090064;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_DarkActionBar=0x7f0900b4;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog=0x7f090014;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert=0x7f090015;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_FixedSize=0x7f0900b5;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_MinWidth=0x7f090016;
    public static final int Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light_DialogWhenLarge=0x7f090002;
    public static final int Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat=0x7f0900b6;
    public static final int Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_ActionBar=0x7f0900b7;
    public static final int Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark=0x7f0900b8;
    public static final int Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar=0x7f0900b9;
    public static final int Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f090017;
    public static final int Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert=0x7f090018;
    public static final int Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Light=0x7f0900ba;
    public static final int Base_V11_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f090019;
    public static final int Base_V11_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog=0x7f09001a;
    public static final int Base_V11_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f09001b;
    public static final int Base_V12_Widget_AppCompat_AutoCompleteTextView=0x7f090023;
    public static final int Base_V12_Widget_AppCompat_EditText=0x7f090024;
    public static final int Base_V21_Theme_AppCompat=0x7f090065;
    public static final int Base_V21_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f090066;
    public static final int Base_V21_Theme_AppCompat_Light=0x7f090067;
    public static final int Base_V21_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog=0x7f090068;
    public static final int Base_V21_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f090069;
    public static final int Base_V22_Theme_AppCompat=0x7f090095;
    public static final int Base_V22_Theme_AppCompat_Light=0x7f090096;
    public static final int Base_V23_Theme_AppCompat=0x7f090099;
    public static final int Base_V23_Theme_AppCompat_Light=0x7f09009a;
    public static final int Base_V7_Theme_AppCompat=0x7f0900bb;
    public static final int Base_V7_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f0900bc;
    public static final int Base_V7_Theme_AppCompat_Light=0x7f0900bd;
    public static final int Base_V7_Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog=0x7f0900be;
    public static final int Base_V7_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f0900bf;
    public static final int Base_V7_Widget_AppCompat_AutoCompleteTextView=0x7f0900c0;
    public static final int Base_V7_Widget_AppCompat_EditText=0x7f0900c1;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar=0x7f0900c2;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_Solid=0x7f0900c3;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TabBar=0x7f0900c4;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TabText=0x7f09006a;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TabView=0x7f09006b;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton=0x7f09006c;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton_CloseMode=0x7f09006d;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton_Overflow=0x7f09006e;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActionMode=0x7f0900c5;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ActivityChooserView=0x7f0900c6;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_AutoCompleteTextView=0x7f090025;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Button=0x7f09006f;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless=0x7f090070;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless_Colored=0x7f090071;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Button_ButtonBar_AlertDialog=0x7f0900c7;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Button_Colored=0x7f09009b;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Button_Small=0x7f090072;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ButtonBar=0x7f090073;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ButtonBar_AlertDialog=0x7f0900c8;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_CompoundButton_CheckBox=0x7f090074;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_CompoundButton_RadioButton=0x7f090075;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_CompoundButton_Switch=0x7f0900c9;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_DrawerArrowToggle=0x7f090000;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_DrawerArrowToggle_Common=0x7f0900ca;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_DropDownItem_Spinner=0x7f090076;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_EditText=0x7f090026;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ImageButton=0x7f090077;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Light_ActionBar=0x7f0900cb;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Light_ActionBar_Solid=0x7f0900cc;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Light_ActionBar_TabBar=0x7f0900cd;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Light_ActionBar_TabText=0x7f090078;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Light_ActionBar_TabText_Inverse=0x7f090079;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Light_ActionBar_TabView=0x7f09007a;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Light_PopupMenu=0x7f09007b;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Light_PopupMenu_Overflow=0x7f09007c;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ListMenuView=0x7f0900ce;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ListPopupWindow=0x7f09007d;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ListView=0x7f09007e;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ListView_DropDown=0x7f09007f;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ListView_Menu=0x7f090080;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_PopupMenu=0x7f090081;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_PopupMenu_Overflow=0x7f090082;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_PopupWindow=0x7f0900cf;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ProgressBar=0x7f09001c;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_ProgressBar_Horizontal=0x7f09001d;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_RatingBar=0x7f090083;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_RatingBar_Indicator=0x7f09009c;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_RatingBar_Small=0x7f09009d;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_SearchView=0x7f0900d0;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_SearchView_ActionBar=0x7f0900d1;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_SeekBar=0x7f090084;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_SeekBar_Discrete=0x7f0900d2;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Spinner=0x7f090085;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Spinner_Underlined=0x7f090003;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_TextView_SpinnerItem=0x7f090086;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Toolbar=0x7f0900d3;
    public static final int Base_Widget_AppCompat_Toolbar_Button_Navigation=0x7f090087;
    public static final int CentralTheme=0x7f0900d4;
    public static final int CircleTheme=0x7f0900d5;
    public static final int DLRTheme=0x7f0900d6;
    public static final int DistrictTheme=0x7f0900d7;
    public static final int MetropolitanTheme=0x7f0900d8;
    public static final int NorthernTheme=0x7f0900d9;
    public static final int OvergroundTheme=0x7f0900da;
    public static final int PiccadillyTheme=0x7f0900db;
    public static final int Platform_AppCompat=0x7f09001e;
    public static final int Platform_AppCompat_Light=0x7f09001f;
    public static final int Platform_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat=0x7f090088;
    public static final int Platform_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark=0x7f090089;
    public static final int Platform_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Light=0x7f09008a;
    public static final int Platform_V11_AppCompat=0x7f090020;
    public static final int Platform_V11_AppCompat_Light=0x7f090021;
    public static final int Platform_V14_AppCompat=0x7f090028;
    public static final int Platform_V14_AppCompat_Light=0x7f090029;
    public static final int Platform_V21_AppCompat=0x7f09008b;
    public static final int Platform_V21_AppCompat_Light=0x7f09008c;
    public static final int Platform_V25_AppCompat=0x7f0900a0;
    public static final int Platform_V25_AppCompat_Light=0x7f0900a1;
    public static final int Platform_Widget_AppCompat_Spinner=0x7f090022;
    public static final int Preference=0x7f0900dc;
    public static final int Preference_Category=0x7f0900dd;
    public static final int Preference_Category_Material=0x7f0900de;
    public static final int Preference_CheckBoxPreference=0x7f0900df;
    public static final int Preference_CheckBoxPreference_Material=0x7f0900e0;
    public static final int Preference_DialogPreference=0x7f0900e1;
    public static final int Preference_DialogPreference_EditTextPreference=0x7f0900e2;
    public static final int Preference_DialogPreference_EditTextPreference_Material=0x7f0900e3;
    public static final int Preference_DialogPreference_Material=0x7f0900e4;
    public static final int Preference_DropDown=0x7f0900e5;
    public static final int Preference_DropDown_Material=0x7f0900e6;
    public static final int Preference_Information=0x7f0900e7;
    public static final int Preference_Information_Material=0x7f0900e8;
    public static final int Preference_Material=0x7f0900e9;
    public static final int Preference_PreferenceScreen=0x7f0900ea;
    public static final int Preference_PreferenceScreen_Material=0x7f0900eb;
    public static final int Preference_SeekBarPreference=0x7f0900ec;
    public static final int Preference_SwitchPreference=0x7f0900ed;
    public static final int Preference_SwitchPreference_Material=0x7f0900ee;
    public static final int Preference_SwitchPreferenceCompat=0x7f0900ef;
    public static final int Preference_SwitchPreferenceCompat_Material=0x7f0900f0;
    public static final int PreferenceFragment=0x7f090031;
    public static final int PreferenceFragment_Material=0x7f0900f1;
    public static final int PreferenceFragmentList=0x7f090032;
    public static final int PreferenceFragmentList_Material=0x7f090033;
    public static final int PreferenceThemeOverlay=0x7f0900f2;
    public static final int PreferenceThemeOverlay_v14=0x7f0900f3;
    public static final int PreferenceThemeOverlay_v14_Material=0x7f0900f4;
    public static final int Preference_TextAppearanceMaterialBody2=0x7f0900f5;
    public static final int Preference_TextAppearanceMaterialSubhead=0x7f0900f6;
    public static final int PreferencesTheme=0x7f0900f7;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_DialogWindowTitle_AppCompat=0x7f090034;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TitleItem=0x7f090035;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_DialogTitle_Icon=0x7f090036;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_PopupMenuItem=0x7f090037;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_PopupMenuItem_InternalGroup=0x7f090038;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_PopupMenuItem_Text=0x7f090039;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_Search_DropDown=0x7f09003a;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_Search_DropDown_Icon1=0x7f09003b;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_Search_DropDown_Icon2=0x7f09003c;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_Search_DropDown_Query=0x7f09003d;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_Search_DropDown_Text=0x7f09003e;
    public static final int RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_SearchView_MagIcon=0x7f09003f;
    public static final int RtlUnderlay_Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton=0x7f090040;
    public static final int RtlUnderlay_Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton_Overflow=0x7f090041;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat=0x7f0900f8;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Body1=0x7f0900f9;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Body2=0x7f0900fa;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Button=0x7f0900fb;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Caption=0x7f0900fc;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Display1=0x7f0900fd;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Display2=0x7f0900fe;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Display3=0x7f0900ff;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Display4=0x7f090100;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Headline=0x7f090101;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Inverse=0x7f090102;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Large=0x7f090103;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Large_Inverse=0x7f090104;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Light_SearchResult_Subtitle=0x7f090105;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Light_SearchResult_Title=0x7f090106;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Light_Widget_PopupMenu_Large=0x7f090107;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Light_Widget_PopupMenu_Small=0x7f090108;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Medium=0x7f090109;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Medium_Inverse=0x7f09010a;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Menu=0x7f09010b;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification=0x7f09002a;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Info=0x7f09008d;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Info_Media=0x7f09008e;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Line2=0x7f09010c;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Line2_Media=0x7f09010d;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Media=0x7f09008f;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Time=0x7f090090;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Time_Media=0x7f090091;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Title=0x7f09002b;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Notification_Title_Media=0x7f090092;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_SearchResult_Subtitle=0x7f09010e;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_SearchResult_Title=0x7f09010f;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Small=0x7f090110;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Small_Inverse=0x7f090111;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Subhead=0x7f090112;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Subhead_Inverse=0x7f090113;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Title=0x7f090114;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Title_Inverse=0x7f090115;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Menu=0x7f090116;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Subtitle=0x7f090117;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Subtitle_Inverse=0x7f090118;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Title=0x7f090119;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionBar_Title_Inverse=0x7f09011a;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionMode_Subtitle=0x7f09011b;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionMode_Subtitle_Inverse=0x7f09011c;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionMode_Title=0x7f09011d;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_ActionMode_Title_Inverse=0x7f09011e;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Button=0x7f09011f;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Button_Borderless_Colored=0x7f090120;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Button_Colored=0x7f090121;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Button_Inverse=0x7f090122;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_DropDownItem=0x7f090123;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_PopupMenu_Header=0x7f090124;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_PopupMenu_Large=0x7f090125;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_PopupMenu_Small=0x7f090126;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_Switch=0x7f090127;
    public static final int TextAppearance_AppCompat_Widget_TextView_SpinnerItem=0x7f090128;
    public static final int TextAppearance_StatusBar_EventContent=0x7f09002c;
    public static final int TextAppearance_StatusBar_EventContent_Info=0x7f09002d;
    public static final int TextAppearance_StatusBar_EventContent_Line2=0x7f09002e;
    public static final int TextAppearance_StatusBar_EventContent_Time=0x7f09002f;
    public static final int TextAppearance_StatusBar_EventContent_Title=0x7f090030;
    public static final int TextAppearance_Widget_AppCompat_ExpandedMenu_Item=0x7f090129;
    public static final int TextAppearance_Widget_AppCompat_Toolbar_Subtitle=0x7f09012a;
    public static final int TextAppearance_Widget_AppCompat_Toolbar_Title=0x7f09012b;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat=0x7f09012c;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_CompactMenu=0x7f09012d;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_DayNight=0x7f090004;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_DarkActionBar=0x7f090005;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog=0x7f090006;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert=0x7f090007;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_MinWidth=0x7f090008;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_DialogWhenLarge=0x7f090009;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_NoActionBar=0x7f09000a;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f09012e;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert=0x7f09012f;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_MinWidth=0x7f090130;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_DialogWhenLarge=0x7f090131;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Light=0x7f090132;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Light_DarkActionBar=0x7f090133;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog=0x7f090134;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert=0x7f090135;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_MinWidth=0x7f090136;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Light_DialogWhenLarge=0x7f090137;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar=0x7f090138;
    public static final int Theme_AppCompat_NoActionBar=0x7f090139;
    public static final int ThemeOverlay_AppCompat=0x7f09013a;
    public static final int ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_ActionBar=0x7f09013b;
    public static final int ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark=0x7f09013c;
    public static final int ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar=0x7f09013d;
    public static final int ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog=0x7f09013e;
    public static final int ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert=0x7f09013f;
    public static final int ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Light=0x7f090140;
    public static final int Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar=0x7f090141;
    public static final int Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_Solid=0x7f090142;
    public static final int Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TabBar=0x7f090143;
    public static final int Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TabText=0x7f090144;
    public static final int Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TabView=0x7f090145;
    public static final int Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton=0x7f090146;
    public static final int Widget_AppCompat_ActionButton_CloseMode=0x7f090147;
}
```

app.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hello.world"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.lawloretienne:trestle:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.marcoscgdev:HeaderDialog:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken - are we talking about a **single** Java source code file here? (that is how I read your screenshot)

Comment: @GhostCat That file contains all constants for my project

Comment: Why do you need 3GB of constants for?

Comment: @GhostCat R is a generated file

Comment: I guess we still agree that it seems to be pretty ... large.

Comment: @GhostCat Especially since it's just a bunch of static final integers

Comment: @litelite I removed Android Support library from my project but the constants for that sill remain when I don't even need them. How can they be remove completely?

Comment: @MacaronLover Looks in you xml files. They must be declared somewhere in there.

Comment: @litelite I thought MultiDex was supposed to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's not the Java limit, just a limitation in IntelliJ's code inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `Help` menu and choose `Edit Custom Properties`. From there you can add or edit the `idea.max.intellisense.filesize` property to whatever you need, e.g. `idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500`. This should let you get intellisense features while working with larger files, as the name implies.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#customize_ide)

Comment: Tried that but that didn't work for me at all. I still get the 'too many constants' error.

Comment: The number would have to be higher though (assuming the option is the correct one anyway), like 5000.